# Interpreting sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats, especially inequality_columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-performance

I'm getting several suggestions for missing indexes for the sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats table in SQL Server (I'm using 2008 R2).

I need help interpreting the recommendations.

For some, there are recommendations in both the equality_columns column and the inequality_columns column. I know that order can affect the effectiveness of an index. So with that assumption, is there a recommendation for creating an index from these entries.

For instance, if equality_columns is suggesting [A], [B] and inequality_columns is suggesting [C], [D], should I create an index with the order of A,B,C,D or should I do C,D,A,B?

Or does it matter? Or should I test both?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how I missed this and I hate to answer my own question but I found this in the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345421.aspx

When writing the CREATE INDEX DDL statement to implement missing indexes, list equality columns first and then inequality columns in the ON  clause of the CREATE INDEX statement.

Leaving for the historical record.